# Yahoo BOSS API: Related Searches

Tags: search, yahoo, yahoo-api

Does anyone know if Yahoo BOSS can return Related Searches? For example, when I search for "Tennis Eblow", Google returns at the bottom on search results page like:

Searches related to Tennis Elbow

tennis elbow brace
tennis elbow exercises
tennis elbow treatment
tennis elbow symptoms
golfers elbow
tennis elbow surgery
elbow pain
tennis elbow causes

And Yahoo returns:

RELATED SEARCHES

```
golfers elbow
elbow pain
bursitis
tendinitis
golf elbow
```

I need to add feature but I didn't find any information about this in Y! BOSS API document.

Answer (score 4):

BOSS just launched a Related Search feature yesterday http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/related.html

Comment: Thanks BOSS Team! But there is a problem that I'm facing. The problem is when I try to send a search request, using Yahoo BOSS api for both Web and
Related Search and if I pass count parameter's value (e.g. '&count=20') it
doesn't return any results and if I pass '&count=10', it returns results.

I wanna fetch top 20 results per query and 10 Related Search results from the
same feed url. And at this point I got stuck.

Please suggest me, how to resolve this problem.

Thanks in Advance! ~Rakesh